# FPDF - image alignment

Tags: fpdf

I've been trying to get an image to right align in a cell but have been unable to do so.

The image in question is a variable so I can't simply specify a coordinate as I can never know the width of the graphic. I've also tried the "R" option in a MultiCell but that appears to only work for text?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading an image, you could use php to [capture the width of the image](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) prior to drawing it on the page. Then simply subtract that width from the width of your .pdf page to 'fake' right alignment.